# Infinite group having composition series

Tags: group-theory

Example of an infinite group having composition series.
I have examples as infinite alternating group and projective special linear group.
But I want example other than infinite simple group.

Comment: Take a direct product of an infinite simple group with a finite group.

Answer (score 3):

Does $\operatorname{PSL}(2, \mathbb{Q})\times A_{\infty}$ and other, similar constructions, satisfy your appetite?

More subtle examples are extensions of infinite simple groups by finite groups. For example, the permutations of the natural numbers with finite support is an extension of $A_{\infty}$,
$$1\rightarrow A_{\infty}\rightarrow S_{\infty}\rightarrow C_2\rightarrow 1$$
and is easily seen to have a composition series.